# Nexus 5 can't connect to Bluetooth Headphones

Tags: nexus-5, bluetooth, 6.0-marshmallow

My headphones (Philips SHB9150BK) used to work properly with my Nexus 5 until version 6.0.0. Since the last update to 6.0.1, it isn't even discoverable anymore. I still can connect the headphones to other devices, though, and it's working as always.

Has anyone experienced this before? How can I troubleshoot this?